# BCP : Retaining null values as '\N'

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2008, bcp

Have to move a table from **MS SQL Server** to **MySQL** (~ 8M rows with 8 coloumns). One of the coloumns (DECIMAL Type) is exported as empty string with `"bcp"` export to a csv file. When I'm using this csv file to load data into MySQL table, it fails saying "Incorrect decimal value". 
Looking for possible work arounds or suggestions.

Comment: That sounds like it depends on your current export method; you might want to elaborate that. I'm not very familiar with MS SQL, but I would think "worst case scenario", you could convert the column to a VARCHAR.

Comment: You want null values to be newlines?  Or did you mean \0?

Comment: @Uueerdo I'm exporting the table with following command "bcp <tableName> out <csv_file_path> -c -T".

Comment: @BaconBits : Not new lines, "load data " command in mysql treats "\N" as null.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a view in MS SQL which converts the decimal column to a varchar column:

```
CREATE VIEW MySQLExport AS
SELECT [...]
    COALESCE(CAST(DecimalColumn AS VARCHAR(50)),'') AS DecimalColumn
FROM SourceTable;
```

Then, import into a staging table in MySQL, and use a CASE statement for the final INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO DestinationTable ([...])
SELECT [...]
    CASE DecimalColumn
        WHEN '' THEN NULL
        ELSE CAST(DecimalColumn AS DECIMAL(10,5))
    END AS DecimalColumn,
    [...]
FROM ImportMSSQLStagingTable;
```

This is safe because the only way the value can be an empty string in the export file is if it's NULL.

Note that I doubt you can cheat by exporting it with `COALESCE(CAST(DecimalColumn AS VARCHAR(50)),'\N')`, because LOAD INFILE would see that as `'\N'`, which is not the same as `\N`.

Comment: thanks for the solution.  we are talking about 8 million rows here. Does the suggested solution has any performance impacts ? The csv file size is close to 2gigs.

Comment: @raka Absolutely it will.  You'll be writing your data twice, for one.  I can't think of any other way to do it via a CSV file, however, since bcp and SSIS only let you use empty fields for NULL values, which MySQL will interpret as 0.  Converting it to a varchar lets you specify a magic value for NULL, but it will show up as a string, which MySQL will convert to 0 when it's inserted.  There's no way to get around the fact that you can't export a NULL in a format that will be understood as a NULL upon import.

Comment: @raka You might try setting up the MySQL server as a Linked Server in MS SQL, but IMX that's not very easy to do and often doesn't perform well with 3rd party providers.  You might try exporting the file with bcp, and then processing the .csv file with PowerShell or sed and replacing the magic value or empty fields from SQL Server with a literal `\N` for MySQL, but that may be error-prone depending on your data or time consuming depending on your implementation.  You could try using an SSIS package to insert the data directly, but, again, you might have issues with the database connection.

Comment: @BacoBits thanks for you valuable input. I really appreciate it.